# Delete a specific file from the list of uploads using valums ajax uploader

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

When uploaded files using **valums ajax uploader** we get the list of files with file name and file size. I wanted the list to come with **file name, file size and a Delete link** for the file. So that when the user clicks on delete the file should get out of the list that are displayed.
I was successful on getting the delete link on each file but as i have less javascript knowledge was unable to process as i wanted. if anybody can help would be great.
This is what i have done uptil now.

```
 function deleteme(id){
 //something like this
     var item = this._getItemByFileId(id);                
     qq.remove(this._find(item));
 }     

fileTemplate:'<li>' +
            '<span class="qq-upload-file"></span>' +
            '<span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
            '<span class="qq-upload-size"></span>' +
            '<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>' +
            '<span class="qq-upload-failed-text">Failed</span>' +
            '<a class="qq-upload-del-text" href="javascript:deleteme(this.id);">Delete</a>' +
            '</li>',
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the FileUploaderBasic version and faced the same problem. So I did a DIY remove

Here is the full example:

```
var $fub = $('#fine-uploader-basic'),
                                    $messages = $('#upload-messages');

                                // try the basic uploader 

                                var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
                                        button: $fub[0],
                                        action: base_ajax_url + 'upload',
                                        debug: true,
                                        autoUpload: false,
                                        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                                        sizeLimit: 204800, // 200 kB = 200 * 1024 bytes
                                        // the method name really should be onSelect 
                                        onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {

                                            var _self = this;

                                            var entry = $('<div id="file-' + id + '" class="alert" style="margin: 10px 0 0">' + fileName + ' <span class="qq-upload-cancel close">&times;</span></div>'
                                                ).appendTo(
                                                    $messages[0]
                                                ).find('.qq-upload-cancel').click(function() {
                                                    _self._storedFileIds.splice(_self._storedFileIds.indexOf(id) , 1);
                                                    $($(this).parent()).remove();
                                                return false;
                                                });

                                        },
                                        onUpload: function(id, fileName) {
                                            $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info')
                                                .html('<img src="/sites/all/themes/pb_admin/images/loading.gif" alt="Initializing. Please hold."> ' +
                                                'Initializing ' +
                                                '"' + fileName + '"');
                                        },
                                        onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total) {
                                            if (loaded < total) {
                                              progress = Math.round(loaded / total * 100) + '% of ' + Math.round(total / 1024) + ' kB';
                                              $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                                                              .html('<img src="/sites/all/themes/pb_admin/images/loader.gif" alt="In progress. Please hold."> ' +
                                                                    'Uploading ' +
                                                                    '"' + fileName + '" ' +
                                                                    progress);
                                            } else {
                                              $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info')
                                                              .html('<img src="/sites/all/themes/pb_admin/images/loader.gif" alt="Saving. Please hold."> ' +
                                                                    'Saving ' +
                                                                    '"' + fileName + '"');
                                            }
                                        },
                                        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                                            if (responseJSON.success) {
                                              $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                                                              .addClass('alert-success')
                                                              .html('<i class="icon-ok"></i> ' +
                                                                    'Successfully saved ' +
                                                                    '"' + fileName + '"');
                                            } else {
                                              $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                                                              .addClass('alert-error')
                                                              .html('<i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> ' +
                                                                    'Error with ' +
                                                                    '"' + fileName + '": ' +
                                                                    responseJSON.error);
                                            }
                                        }
                                     });
```

(The name onSubmit kinda questionable ... anyway)

I tried to call the onCancel method (but throw exception that is undefined).

Then this one works - by remove the id from the **_storedFileIds** array. And that's it.